# Does not name a type error is due to existing enum, but why?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, name-hiding

I was just getting this error: "error: ‘Symbol’ does not name a type"

I found some other StackOverflow questions talking about circular dependencies, but that is not the case here. In fact I could reproduce it by putting this at the top of the source file:

```
class Symbol{int dummy;};
//class Symbol{int again;};
Symbol global_symbol;
```

This gives "error: ‘Symbol’ does not name a type" for the 3rd line. If I uncomment the 2nd line, I still get that same error, but just before it I now get: "error: redefinition of ‘class Symbol’" !!

After lots more poking around it appears a 3rd party library has an `enum` where `Symbol` is defined. Neither that library, nor my own code, uses namespaces, so as moving my code to be inside a namespace was already on my to-do list I'll do that next and hopefully the problem will go away.

But what confuses me is why I didn't get an error on the `class Symbol{}` line? If it clashes with an enum, to the extent that I would never be able to instantiate that class, why didn't it complain? I feel like I'm either missing a flag for `g++`, or there is a gap in my C++ knowledge. I'm bracing myself for someone to tell me this is a feature not a bug.

(BTW I am using `g++ -c -std=gnu++0x -Wall -g -Werror ...` and g++ 4.8.1)

Comment: g++ 2.8 is very old. Try to compile with a newer version

Comment: @BЈовић Thanks! I meant 4.8, just fixed. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is a form of *name hiding*: a declaration of an variable or function `Symbol` will be found in preference to `class Symbol` ([basic.scope.hiding] §3.3.10/2). In the cases where C++ allows one declaration to hide another in the same scope, there is always an *elaborated-type-specifier* which still refers to the hidden declaration. They are so named because only a type (`class` or `enum`) may be hidden in this way; typedefs and templates cannot. The order of declaration is not significant.

In this case, you can use `class Symbol` to refer to the class when the variable or function is in scope:

```
class Symbol global_symbol;
```

Comment: Thanks, the ability to use an "elaborated-type-specifier" was indeed a corner of C++ I didn't know about. (And so if this is possible I can see how the compiler would not report it as an error to have class and enum with the same name.)

Answer (score 2):

`gcc` error messages are not the most user friendly, due to the fact that `C++` has quite a complicated syntax and the parser sometimes gets totally confused by the smallest error, such as a missing `;`. For example, your code of the form

```
enum A{Symbol=0};

class Symbol{int dummy;};

int main() 
{
    Symbol global_symbol;
}
```

where an `enum` having a `Symbol` is declared before the `class Symbol` gives me the following compiling error (I use `g++4.8`):

```
minimal.cpp: In function 'int main()':
minimal.cpp:13:9: error: expected ';' before 'global_symbol'
  Symbol global_symbol;
         ^
minimal.cpp:13:22: warning: statement has no effect [-Wunused-value]
  Symbol global_symbol;
```

So the best thing to do is to use namespaces in your code, or change the class name :) 
And you mentioned you used `g++2.8`. You meant `2.8` or `4.8`? `2.8` is quite antique (16 years old), so it's not even fully `C++98` compliant.